# How to know if there any fetched data in the Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to find if there is a way to know if there is fetched data in the Firebase realtime database.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // ARRAY
    accountList = new ArrayList<>();
    // Assigning Object to Controls (bullshit)
    textboxUser = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textBoxUsername);
    textboxPass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textBoxPassword);
    buttonEnter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonEnter);

    postRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("account");
    dataRefaccount = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("account");


    // OnClick Method Button
    buttonEnter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                username = textboxUser.getText().toString();
                Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("account").orderByChild("username").equalTo(username);
                query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }



        }
    });
}

ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            if (data.child(username).exists()) {
                getted = "yes";
            } else {
                getted = "No";
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};
```

The getter is always "NO".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have to try this. First make sure you are not getting any error in query response.

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("account").orderByChild("username").equalTo(username);

ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { 
        if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null && dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0) {
           for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                // I'm sure you are looking for below line.. Go and try this.
                if (data.child("username").getValue().toString().equal(username) ) {
                  getted = "yes";
                  break;
                } else {
                  getted = "No";
                }
           }
        } else {
            getted = No value available;
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "getted : " + getted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { 
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    } 
};
```

**FYI : Firebase calls is asynchronous call, so the finally clause on button click will always execute before the response from the firebase. So try to remove try-catch from there and use above code to print *getted* value.**

Comment: Thanks. I'm also having the same problem. I forgot that firebase query make async call to firebase database.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the `DataSnapshot` exists by calling the following:

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("account").orderByChild("username").equalTo(username);

ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { 
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            getted = yes;
        }else{
            getted = no;
        }
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { 
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    } 
};
```

By providing your database structure it would be easier to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> ***The only method that is allowed by the firebase community to retrieve data is: You should try the code below as for fetched
>   Username:***

```
DatabaseReference bDatabaseRef;
bDatabaseRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");           bDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           if(dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()>0){
               Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

               if(map.get("Username")!=null){

                   String User_name =map.get("Username").toString();

               }



           }
       }
       @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
       }
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to use the following line of code:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

The value of `getted` will always hold the value of `No`, since by the time you are trying to toast that message, the data hasn't finished loading yet from the database. This is happening because the asynchronous behaviour of `onDataChange()` method. Please note, that there are no guarantees about how long it will take, it may take from a few hundred milliseconds to a few seconds before that data is available.

A quick solve for this problem would be to use all the logic that is related to the `getted` variable only inside or called from inside the `onDataChange()` method.

If you need to use it outside the callback, I recommend you see the last part of my anwser from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774)** in which I have explained how it can be done using a custom callback. You can also take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvDZVV5CbQg)** for a better understanding.